# Is the median a measurable function of the probability distribution?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, continuity, measurable-functions, median

For $\mu \in \mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, let $m(\mu)$ be the median of $\mu$, defined as the smallest of all medians of $\mu$ as follows:
$$
m(\mu) = \inf \left\{ x \in \mathbb R \,\middle|\, \mu((-\infty,x]) \ge \frac12 \right\}.
$$

Assume that $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ is endowed with the weak convergence topology. Then, $m$ is not continuous as, for exemple, $\mu_n = (\frac12-\frac 1 n) \delta_0 + (\frac12 + \frac 1 n) \delta_1$ weakly converges to $\mu = \frac12(\delta_0+\delta_1)$, but $m(\mu_n)=1$ for all n while $m(\mu)=0$. (Counter exemple given in a comment, thanks)

Now, endow $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ with the Borel sigma algebra associated to the above topology. Is $m$ measurable?

Comment: How do you define the median? If it's any value $m$ such that $P(X \leq m) = 0.5$ then it's a set valued function and you'd need to tell us the topology of the target space

Comment: @JoseAvilez, thank you for your remark; I edited the question to clarify the meaning of "median": it is classically the smallest of all medians.

Comment: In that case won't a sequence like $\mu_n = (\frac 12 - \frac 1n) \delta_0 + (\frac 12 + \frac 1n) \delta_1$ show $m$ is discontinuous? I'm not sure about measurability at the moment.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, I agree with your example, thank you! Measurability remains an open question then...